# how to remove definer in mysql create trigger function or add multiple definer

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

currently in my mysql triggers there are delimeters and it is only limited to one account, but I have multiple account and I wan't to be able to use all of them in my trigger, so I'm wondering if you can remove a delimeter, or add multiple accounts in a delimeter

Comment: The delimiter has nothing to do with the account. It just allows you to have multiple statements in the trigger body.

Comment: Create an account that has access to all the tables the trigger uses, and use that as the definer.